# Why does the function not work without the "if" statement?

Tags: kotlin

This function returns a list containing all numbers from n to 0.
If I deleted the "if" statement the function doesn't work, even if the parameters aren't 0.
Why is that?

```
fun countDown (n : Int): List<Int> {
    if (n == 0) {
        return listOf(0)
    }

    return mutableListOf(n).also { it.addAll(countDown(n - 1)) }
}
```

Comment: You deleted the base case from your recursive function, so the inevitable result is infinite recursion. I'd expect it to quickly fail with `StackOverflowException`, though.

Comment: What does "not working" mean in your context? Any error message?

Comment: Also note this is a very bad implementation performance-wise. It copies the data with each step, therefore it is quadratic. Why not to use builtin `n downTo 0`?

Comment: I just noticed that it's indeed a recursive function.

Comment: The error is -> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError.
I used  (n downTo 0) but was trying another solution.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code calls `it.addAll(countDown(n-1))`, specifically calling `countDown(n-1)`

So a direct call to, say, `countDown(3)` will call `countDown(2)`; `countDown(2)` calls `countDown(1)`; `countDown(1)` calls `countDown(0)`.

Comment: …and, without the `if`, that would call `countDown(-1)`, which would call `countDown(-2)`, which would call `countDown(-3)`, and so on until it ran out of stack space.